# LINQ: Count Users in 3 way join

Tags: linq-to-sql, count

I'm having trouble with LINQ to SQL, which I think should not be too difficult.
In SQL I have a BusinessUnits, that get's divided in OrgUnits, and Users belong to an Org Unit.
I want to print the BusinessUnitID with the number of Users in each.

In SQL, it will probably look like this:

```
SELECT BusinessUnitID, Count(u.UserID)
FROM BusinessUnitsOrgUnits bu
     INNER JOIN OrgUnits org on bu.OrgUnitID= org.OrgUnitID
     INNER JOIN Users u on org.OrgUnitID = u.OrgUnitID
GROUP BY BusinessUnitID
```

But in LINQ I got this, but struggling to get the count correct.

```
 var UsersPerBU = from bu in BusinessUnitsOrgUnits 
                  join org in OrgUnits on bu.OrgUnitID equals org.OrgUnitID
                  join u in Users on org.OrgUnitID equals u.OrgUnitID
                  group bu by bu.BusinessUnitID into g
                  select new
                   {
                        BusinessUnitID = g.Key,
                        UserCount = Users.Count (us => us.OrgUnit.OrgUnitID == bu.OrgUnitID) 
                         //here it complains that bu does not exist.
                   };
```

Comment: I think you might be right. Seems to be working. So simple.  If you compile the comment as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var UsersPerBU = from bu in BusinessUnitsOrgUnits 
                  join org in OrgUnits on bu.OrgUnitID equals org.OrgUnitID
                  join u in Users on org.OrgUnitID equals u.OrgUnitID
                  group bu by bu.BusinessUnitID into g
                  select new
                   {
                        BusinessUnitID = g.Key,
                        UserCount = g.Count()
                   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this

```
            var UsersPerBU = (from bu in BusinessUnitsOrgUnits
                              join org in OrgUnits on bu.OrgUnitID equals org.OrgUnitID
                              join u in Users on org.OrgUnitID equals u.OrgUnitID
                              group bu by bu.BusinessUnitID into g
                              select new { bu = g})
                             .Select(x =>
                                 new
                                 {

                                     BusinessUnitID = x,
                                     UserCount = x.bu.Select(y  => y.OrgUnitID).Distinct().Count()
                                     //here it complains that bu does not exist
                                 }
                            );
```